# SSRS Printing without showind Print Dialog

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

I am rendering an SSRS datareport.  I want to print it directly, without showing it on screen and without even showing the printer dialogue.
I can send it to the printer without showing on screen but it displays the Print Dialog.
How to avoid this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of threading here. Once the print command is given just start a thread which will simulate the key press required to close the window..

Here is a sample code which closes a dialogue box which requires enter key to be pressed.

Start the thread after print starts:

```
'Declare a thread object to do the keyboard press events.
 Dim thrd as Thread

    thrd = New Thread(AddressOf ThreadTask)
    thrd.IsBackground = True
    thrd.Start()
```

This is the thread task, which here is to simulate enter key press which results in closing the window. You can use escape key if it works for you

```
Private Sub ThreadTask()
    Thread.Sleep(100)
    SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}")
    Thread.Sleep(10)
    SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}")
End Sub
```