# Printing a Report Server-Side and Silently

Tags: c#, printing, report, server-side, silent

I am trying to write a program that allows me to print a ssrs report(.rdl file) from the server-side code to a predetermined printer without any pop ups asking me which printer I want to use can this be done?

Comment: What kind of report is it? The question is impossible to answer generally, we need to know what kind of report it is. Please tag appropriately.

Comment: Sorry ssrs report like an .rdl file

Comment: Just to clarify - the printer is on the same network as your server, and not your client?

Comment: Yes the client server and printer are all on the same network

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT**
Also pasted the code for the `ReportViewerDisposer` implementation I'm using.

Together with the class `ReportViewerDisposer` found [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsreportcontrols/thread/d21f8b56-3123-4aff-bf84-9cce727bc2ce) I'm using the following code, which is part of a larger project, but you should be able to adapt it easily:

```
private string m_printerName;
private string m_server;
private string m_path;
private string m_name;
private Dictionary<string, string> m_parameters;
private SizeF m_pageSize;
private float m_marginLeft;
private float m_marginTop;
private float m_marginRight;
private float m_marginBottom;
private short m_copies;

private int m_currentPageIndex;
private List<Stream> m_reportStreams;

public void PrintReport()
{
    string mime, extension;

    ReportViewer viewer = new ReportViewer();
    ReportViewerDisposer disposer = new ReportViewerDisposer(viewer);
    try
    {
    viewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
    viewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(String.Format("http://{0}/ReportServer", m_server));
    viewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = String.Format("/{0}/{1}", m_path, m_name);

    List<ReportParameter> param = new List<ReportParameter>();
    foreach (ReportParameterInfo paramInfo in viewer.ServerReport.GetParameters())
    {
        if (m_parameters.ContainsKey(paramInfo.Name.ToUpperInvariant()))
        {
        string value = m_parameters[paramInfo.Name.ToUpperInvariant()];
        param.Add(new ReportParameter(paramInfo.Name, value));
        }
    }

    viewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(param);
    viewer.RefreshReport();

    CultureInfo us = new CultureInfo("en-US");
    string deviceInfo = String.Format(
      "<DeviceInfo>" +
      "  <OutputFormat>EMF</OutputFormat>" +
      "  <PageWidth>{0}cm</PageWidth>" +
      "  <PageHeight>{1}cm</PageHeight>" +
      "  <MarginTop>{2}cm</MarginTop>" +
      "  <MarginLeft>{3}cm</MarginLeft>" +
      "  <MarginRight>{4}cm</MarginRight>" +
      "  <MarginBottom>{5}cm</MarginBottom>" +
      "</DeviceInfo>",
      Math.Round(m_pageSize.Width, 2).ToString(us),
      Math.Round(m_pageSize.Height, 2).ToString(us),
      Math.Round(m_marginTop, 2).ToString(us),
      Math.Round(m_marginLeft, 2).ToString(us),
      Math.Round(m_marginRight, 2).ToString(us),
      Math.Round(m_marginBottom, 2).ToString(us));

    m_reportStreams = new List<Stream>();
    try
    {
        NameValueCollection urlAccessParameters = new NameValueCollection();
        urlAccessParameters.Add("rs:PersistStreams", "True");

        Stream s = viewer.ServerReport.Render("IMAGE", deviceInfo, urlAccessParameters, out mime, out extension);
        m_reportStreams.Add(s);

        urlAccessParameters.Remove("rs:PersistStreams");
        urlAccessParameters.Add("rs:GetNextStream", "True");
        do
        {
        s = viewer.ServerReport.Render("IMAGE", deviceInfo, urlAccessParameters, out mime, out extension);
        if (s.Length != 0) m_reportStreams.Add(s);
        }
        while (s.Length > 0);

        DoPrint();
    }
    finally
    {
        foreach (Stream s in m_reportStreams)
        {
        s.Close();
        s.Dispose();
        }
        m_reportStreams = null;
    }
    }
    finally
    {
    disposer.CollectGarbageOnDispose = true;
    disposer.Dispose();
    }
}


private void DoPrint()
{
    m_currentPageIndex = 0;

    PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
    try
    {
    printDoc.PrintController = new StandardPrintController();
    printDoc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = m_printerName;
    printDoc.PrinterSettings.Copies = m_copies;

    if (!printDoc.PrinterSettings.IsValid)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("Drucker '{0}' ist nicht gültig!", m_printerName));
    }

    // Drucke das Dokument aus
    printDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(PrintPage);
    printDoc.QueryPageSettings += new QueryPageSettingsEventHandler(QueryPageSettings);
    printDoc.Print();
    }
    finally
    {
    printDoc.PrintPage -= new PrintPageEventHandler(PrintPage);
    printDoc.QueryPageSettings -= new QueryPageSettingsEventHandler(QueryPageSettings);
    printDoc.Dispose();
    }
}

private void PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
        {
    if (m_currentPageIndex < m_reportStreams.Count)
    {
    Metafile mf = new Metafile(m_reportStreams[m_currentPageIndex++]);
    try
    {
        ev.Graphics.DrawImage(mf, ev.PageBounds);
    }
    finally
    {
        mf.Dispose();
    }
    }
    ev.HasMorePages = m_currentPageIndex < m_reportStreams.Count;
}


private void QueryPageSettings(object sender, QueryPageSettingsEventArgs e)
{
    e.PageSettings.Landscape = m_pageSize.Width > m_pageSize.Height;
}


private class ReportViewerDisposer : IDisposable
{ 
    // Fields  
    private bool _CollectGarbageOnDispose = true;
    private ReportViewer _ReportViewer;
    private bool disposedValue = false;
    private const string EVENTHANDLER_ON_USER_PREFERENCE_CHANGED = "OnUserPreferenceChanged";
    private const string LIST_HANDLERS = "_handlers";
    private const string ON_USER_PREFERENCE_CHANGED_EVENT = "OnUserPreferenceChangedEvent";
    private const string SYSTEM_EVENT_INVOKE_INFO = "SystemEventInvokeInfo";
    private const string TARGET_DELEGATE = "_delegate";
    private const string TOOLSTRIP_CONTROL_NAME = "reportToolBar";
    private const string TOOLSTRIP_TEXTBOX_CONTROL_NAME_CURRENT_PAGE = "currentPage";
    private const string TOOLSTRIP_TEXTBOX_CONTROL_NAME_TEXT_TO_FIND = "textToFind";

    // Methods  
    public ReportViewerDisposer(ReportViewer rptv)
    {
    if (rptv == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("ReportViewer cannot be null.");
    }
    this._ReportViewer = rptv;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    this.Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
    if (!this.disposedValue && disposing)
    {
        this.TearDownReportViewer();
        this._ReportViewer.Dispose();
        if (this._CollectGarbageOnDispose)
        {
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();
        }
    }
    this.disposedValue = true;
    }

    private void NullRefOnUserPreferenceChanged(object o, string field)
    {
    try
    {
        FieldInfo fi = o.GetType().GetField(field, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        if (fi != null)
        {
        int i;
        ToolStripTextBox tb = (ToolStripTextBox)fi.GetValue(o);
        object tbc = tb.Control;
        Delegate d = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(UserPreferenceChangedEventHandler), tbc, EVENTHANDLER_ON_USER_PREFERENCE_CHANGED);
        object handlers = typeof(SystemEvents).GetField(LIST_HANDLERS, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static).GetValue(null);
        object upcHandler = typeof(SystemEvents).GetField(ON_USER_PREFERENCE_CHANGED_EVENT, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static).GetValue(null);
        object systemEventInvokeInfo = typeof(SystemEvents).GetNestedType(SYSTEM_EVENT_INVOKE_INFO, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        IList upcHandlerList = (IList)((IDictionary)handlers)[upcHandler];
        int targetCount = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < upcHandlerList.Count; i++)
        {
            systemEventInvokeInfo = upcHandlerList[i];
            Delegate target = (Delegate)systemEventInvokeInfo.GetType().GetField(TARGET_DELEGATE, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(systemEventInvokeInfo);
            if (target.Target == d.Target)
            {
            targetCount++;
            }
        }
        for (i = 1; i <= targetCount; i++)
        {
            SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged -= ((UserPreferenceChangedEventHandler)d);
        }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
    }
    } 

    private void TearDownReportViewer()
    {
    FieldInfo fi = this._ReportViewer.GetType().GetField(TOOLSTRIP_CONTROL_NAME, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    if (fi != null)
    {
        object o = fi.GetValue(this._ReportViewer);
        this.NullRefOnUserPreferenceChanged(o, TOOLSTRIP_TEXTBOX_CONTROL_NAME_CURRENT_PAGE);
        this.NullRefOnUserPreferenceChanged(o, TOOLSTRIP_TEXTBOX_CONTROL_NAME_TEXT_TO_FIND);
    }
    }

    // Properties  
    public bool CollectGarbageOnDispose
    {
    get
    {
        return this._CollectGarbageOnDispose;
    }
    set
    {
        this._CollectGarbageOnDispose = value;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, the code in the link you sent me is using NewLateBinding which uses namespace Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices which I cannot find a reference for could you let me know what you are referencing so I can test your code

Comment: I added the `ReportViewerDisposer` to my answer.

Comment: Ok, we are getting somewhere now I assume all the m_* and PrintPage are all class variables and while I can figure out some of them there is some ambiguity in my mind as to what a couple of them are

Comment: Added variable declarations as well.

Comment: Ok, got some empty event handlers for the PrintPage and QueryPageSettings and its printing a blank page and is getting all the parameters for the report this is excellent but I am not getting the report coming out of the printer just a blank sheet I think I need to add to the printpage event handler at least I tried using code from a different site to get this working and it printed out random text instead of the report

Comment: Sorry, forgot the code for the two events. I inserted them in my answer.

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly its nice to have a full solution all in one.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to render your SSRS report into PDF format and then you can print the PDF file directly without opening any popup, Refer to code below:

```
    public void PrintPreviewSSRSReport(string reportName)
    {
        try
        {
            string reportPath = string.Empty;
            string historyID = null;
            string deviceInfo = null;
            string extension = null;
            string encoding = null;
            string mimeType = null;
            string[] streamIDs = null;
            string format = "PDF";
            Byte[] result;

            ReportExecution2005.Warning[] warnings = null;
            ExecutionInfo execInfo = new ExecutionInfo();
            TrustedUserHeader trusteduserHeader = new TrustedUserHeader();
            ExecutionHeader execHeader = new ExecutionHeader();
            ServerInfoHeader serviceInfo = new ServerInfoHeader();
            MHTools.ReportExecution2005.ReportParameter[] _parameters = null;
            ParameterValue[] _ParameterValue = null;

            //Set the report path
            reportPath = "/Reports/SalesReport";

            //Create the object of report execution web service
            ReportExecutionServiceSoapClient rsExec = new ReportExecutionServiceSoapClient();

            //Use this if you don't need to pass the credentials from code
            rsExec.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;

            //Load the reports 
            rsExec.LoadReport(trusteduserHeader, reportPath, historyID, out serviceInfo, out execInfo);
            execHeader.ExecutionID = execInfo.ExecutionID;

            //Get the parameters details from load report and eet the value in paremeters if any
            _parameters = execInfo.Parameters;
            _ParameterValue = new ParameterValue[1];
            _ParameterValue[0] = new ParameterValue();
            _ParameterValue[0].Name = _parameters[0].Name;
            _ParameterValue[0].Value = "12345";

            //Set the parameters
            rsExec.SetExecutionParameters(execHeader, null, _ParameterValue, "en-us", out execInfo);

            //Render the report
            rsExec.Render(execHeader, null, format, deviceInfo, out result, out extension, out mimeType, out encoding, out warnings, out streamIDs);


            //pass the file path where pdf file will be saved
            using (FileStream stream = File.OpenWrite(PDFFile))
            {
                stream.Write(result, 0, result.Length);
            }

            //send the padf file path to printer
            SendFileToPrinter(PDFFile);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //
        }
    }


    #region Print SSRS Report

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    private class DOCINFOA
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string pDocName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string pOutputFile;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string pDataType;
    }

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "OpenPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private static extern bool OpenPrinter([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string szPrinter, out IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pd);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "ClosePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private static extern bool ClosePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartDocPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private static extern bool StartDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, Int32 level, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] DOCINFOA di);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndDocPrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private static extern bool EndDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private static extern bool StartPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private static extern bool EndPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "WritePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private static extern bool WritePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount, out Int32 dwWritten);

    [DllImport("winspool.drv", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool GetDefaultPrinter(StringBuilder pszBuffer, ref int size);

    /// <summary>
    /// This function gets the pdf file name.
    /// This function opens the pdf file, gets all its bytes & send them to print.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="szPrinterName">Printer Name</param>
    /// <param name="szFileName">Pdf File Name</param>
    /// <returns>true on success, false on failure</returns>
    public bool SendFileToPrinter(string pdfFileName)
    {
        try
        {
            #region Get Connected Printer Name
            PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
            StringBuilder dp = new StringBuilder(256);
            int size = dp.Capacity;
            if (GetDefaultPrinter(dp, ref size))
            {
                pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = dp.ToString().Trim();
            }
            #endregion Get Connected Printer Name

            // Open the PDF file.
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(pdfFileName, FileMode.Open);
            // Create a BinaryReader on the file.
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[fs.Length];
            bool success = false;
            // Unmanaged pointer.
            IntPtr ptrUnmanagedBytes = new IntPtr(0);
            int nLength = Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length);
            // Read contents of the file into the array.
            bytes = br.ReadBytes(nLength);
            // Allocate some unmanaged memory for those bytes.
            ptrUnmanagedBytes = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(nLength);
            // Copy the managed byte array into the unmanaged array.
            Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, ptrUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
            // Send the unmanaged bytes to the printer.
            success = SendBytesToPrinter(pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName, ptrUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
            // Free the unmanaged memory that you allocated earlier.
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(ptrUnmanagedBytes);
            return success;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This function gets the printer name and an unmanaged array of bytes, the function sends those bytes to the print queue.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="szPrinterName">Printer Name</param>
    /// <param name="pBytes">No. of bytes in the pdf file</param>
    /// <param name="dwCount">Word count</param>
    /// <returns>True on success, false on failure</returns>
    private bool SendBytesToPrinter(string szPrinterName, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount)
    {
        try
        {
            Int32 dwError = 0, dwWritten = 0;
            IntPtr hPrinter = new IntPtr(0);
            DOCINFOA di = new DOCINFOA();
            bool success = false; // Assume failure unless you specifically succeed.

            di.pDocName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(PDFFile);
            di.pDataType = "RAW";

            // Open the printer.
            if (OpenPrinter(szPrinterName.Normalize(), out hPrinter, IntPtr.Zero))
            {
                // Start a document.
                if (StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, di))
                {
                    // Start a page.
                    if (StartPagePrinter(hPrinter))
                    {
                        // Write the bytes.
                        success = WritePrinter(hPrinter, pBytes, dwCount, out dwWritten);
                        EndPagePrinter(hPrinter);
                    }
                    EndDocPrinter(hPrinter);
                }
                ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
            }

            // If print did not succeed, GetLastError may give more information about the failure.
            if (success == false)
            {
                dwError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            }
            return success;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    #endregion
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First add a Web reference to the Reporting Services Web service in your development project that points to your report server. This can be done by right-clicking on your project in Visual Studio and choosing Add Web reference... . You should add a reference to a local report server (localhost) at "http://localhost/reportserver/reportservice.asmx".
2. Use the ReportingService class to do printing using some steps.

follow [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bryanke/archive/2004/02/11/71491.aspx#code).

Reference links:
[Automatically print SSRS report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480723/automatically-print-ssrs-report)
[SSRS Printing without showind Print Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9532474/ssrs-printing-without-showind-print-dialog)
<s>[Printing Reports Programmatically Using C# and SQL Server 2000 Reporting Services](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bryanke/archive/2004/02/11/71491.aspx)</s>
[Print SSRS Report Automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276599/print-ssrs-report-automatically)
<s>[Printing Reporting Services 2005 Reports](http://scruffylookingcatherder.com/post/2007/12/08/Printing-Reporting-Services-2005-Reports.aspx)</s>